# How to run a protobuf python plugin on Windows

Tags: python, windows, protocol-buffers

I'm currently using a Protobuf plugin to generate some custom C# code given a set of Protobuf files. It is running fine on Linux and I would like to run it on Windows as well in order to generate this code directly from my Visual Studio project.

Here is the command line I am (unsuccessfully) using currently :

```
path\to\protoc.exe --plugin=protoc-gen-my-plugin=path\to\my-plugin.py --my-plugin_out=output\path\gen my_proto.proto
```

And here is the error I'm getting :

> --my-plugin_out: protoc-gen-my-plugin: %1 n'est pas une application Win32 valide.

I have Python 2.7.11 installed and it is in my path. I also tried to run protoc.exe using both x86 and x64 executables.

Is there any limitation I'm not aware of or did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue by encapsulating the python plugin in a .bat file. Here is the code I used :

```
@echo off
chdir path\to\my-plugin
python -u my-plugin.py
```

The "-u" option when running the python script is really important because otherwise the standard input will be buffered. As protoc is passing all the inputs to the plugin (the .proto files to parse) through stdin this is really important. And the output is written by the plugin to stdout, so no issue there.

Here is the final command to execute protoc with my plugin :

```
path\to\protoc.exe --plugin=protoc-gen-my-plugin=redirect.bat --my-plugin_out=output\path\gen my_proto.proto
```